# How to use selectors in /set truncation command in jshell?

Tags: java, selector, java-9, truncation, jshell

I am using jshell and want to truncate the very big message displayed on jshell console.

For this, i got the /set truncate command which says:

> If the values are too long, then they are truncated when displayed. Use the /set truncation command to set the maximum length shown for a value. If no settings are entered with the command, then the current setting is displayed.
>
> Below are the relevant selector kinds for truncation.

```
|  
|  The case selector kind describes the kind of snippet.  The values are:
|   vardecl    -- variable declaration without init
|   varinit    -- variable declaration with init
|   expression -- expression -- note: {name}==scratch-variable-name
|   varvalue   -- variable value expression
|   assignment -- assign variable
|  The action selector kind describes what happened to the snippet.  The values are:
|   added     -- snippet has been added
|   modified  -- an existing snippet has been modified
|   replaced  -- an existing snippet has been replaced with a new snippet
```

Can anybody please suggest the use cases of the case selectors or the action selectors??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> want to truncate the very big message displayed on jshell console.

This relies on what *type of message* do you want to truncate. The ***case*** selector in which shall help you decide the type and ***action*** selector would help you decide when to do so. e.g. adding snippets, modifying etc.

> How to use selectors in /set truncation command in jshell?

The examples from the same documentation lists out these nicely:

```
/set truncation mymode 45 expression
/set truncation mymode 0 varinit-modified,replaced
```

> suggest the use cases of the case selectors or the action selectors??

The documentation for [defining 
a feedback mode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/jshell/feedback-modes.htm#JSHEL-GUID-ED8F7F3B-3667-4724-910A-C93B8521FC84) # **Set truncation** section :

```
mymode: /set truncation mymode 100

mymode: /set truncation mymode 300 varvalue

# default truncation
mymode: String big = IntStream.range(0,1200).mapToObj(n -> "" + (char) ('a' + n % 26)).collect(Collectors.joining())
big ==> "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuv ... fghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcd"

# default truncation
mymode: big + big
$2 ==> "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghi ... yzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcd"

# we can see the overriden truncation value in the next statement
mymode: big
big ==> "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijkl...jklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcd"`
```